# Git operations stopped working from Eclipse (Spring STS) UI - getting "session is being closed error"

Tags: spring, git, eclipse, github, gitlab

Set up GIT via SSH in my Spring STS Tool (based on Eclipse).

It worked fine for months - could pull/push/commit files from the Eclipse UI. I.e., right-click on the repo, then Team and git action.

This has stopped working - for any operation on any repo I get this error:

Pulling 1 repository
git@gitlab.techopscloud.com:.git: Session is being closed

Via the command line, the git works fine as before. Any idea how to fix it in the UI?

How do I re-configure the GIT setup in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Does in the _Git Staging_ view hitting the _Refresh_ button help (if you do something outside of Eclipse, a _Refresh_ is needed)? Is your Eclipse and EGit up to date (please tell the version of both: see _Help > About Eclipse IDE_).

Answer (score 3):

To re-configure the Git setup in Eclipse, follow these steps:

1. Go to Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other...
2. Select Git and click OK.
3. In the Git perspective, go to Window > Show View > Other...
4. Select Git Repositories and click OK.
5. In the Git Repositories view, click the Clone a Git Repository
   button.
6. Enter the repository URL, select Protocol as SSH and provide the
   required credentials.
7. Finish the clone process and your repository should now be available
   in Eclipse.

This should re-configure the Git setup in Eclipse and fix the error you're encountering. If the error persists, you may need to check the settings of your SSH key or the connection to the Git server.